# Running ruby code from vim

Tags: ruby, vim

Is it possible after editing a ruby program in Vim to run it while still in the editor, not using the command line?

Comment: I found this guide useful: http://alisnic.github.io/posts/vim-run-hotkey/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From Vim, you can run the current buffer with :
`:!ruby %`

It might be helpful or not depending on your use case.

Similarly, you invoke any shell command by using `:!command`

Comment: I've tried puts "Hello world", but :!ruby % did that - cmd.exe /c ruby test.rb and Hit any key to close the window... nothing more

Comment: You must probably save your buffer before executing it. So try `:w`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I wanted to tweak the answer by @xavier

Put this in your `.vimrc` and you will be able to run the current ruby script without having to confirm hitting ENTER each time:

```
autocmd BufRead, *.rb nmap <leader>r :silent !{ruby %}<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Xavier ’s solution I recommend binding it in the following way inside your `.vimrc`:

```
" run ruby code using leader-r only when inside a .rb file
au BufRead, *.rb nmap <leader>r :!ruby %<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
For example
lets say i want to write in a document word hello 100000
Now i won't do that manually but i will use ruby script and run it in vim.
In terminal create a new file by typing vim script.rb
Type this code:

```
10000.times do
       puts "hello"
end
```

Before exiting
Press escape then type this:

```
:w ! ruby > testfile.txt
```

press enter
What this will do is that it will run the script in the vim and add the returned string into the text file named testfile. Make sure you have the file in the same directory or you can specify the directory along with the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.

```
function RunWith (command)
  execute "w"
  execute "!clear;" . a:command . " " . expand("%")
endfunction
```

And then, just create shortcut which is only works for ruby. You should to go to the ruby file and press this shortcut :)

```
autocmd FileType ruby nmap <Leader>e :call RunWith("ruby")<cr>
```

You can create shortcut for any file type.
This is javascript example:

```
autocmd FileType js nmap <Leader>e :call RunWith("node")<cr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your '''vimrc''' and save your file

```
ennoremap <C-r> :!ruby %
```

press ctrl+r then enter